# Combine two select queries and remove duplicate column and add grand total

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to combine two select queries together, but I don't know how to remove the duplicate column genre and sum up the number. I've tried to change line1 into :

```
select t1.genre, t1.film_num, t2.rent_times from
```

but Oracle will show an error "invalid identifier" at `t2.rent_times`.

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         genre, count(inventory.film_id) as "film_num"
     from 
         film 
     join 
         inventory using (catalog_num) 
     group by 
         genre) t1
left join
    (select 
         genre, count(rented_item.rental_Num) as "rent_times"
     from 
         film 
     join 
         inventory using (catalog_num)
     join 
         rented_item using(film_id)
     group by 
         genre) t2 on t1.genre = t2.genre;
```

Result:

```
GENRE                       film_num GENRE                      rent_times
------------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
Comedy                             3 Comedy                             3
Sci-Fi                            20 Sci-Fi                             8
Action and Adventure              32 Action and Adventure              15
Children and Family                8 Children and Family                5
```

I want it looks like this:

```
    GENRE                     film_num    rent_times
    ------------------------- ----------  ----------
    Comedy                             3   3
    Sci-Fi                            20   8
    Action and Adventure              32  15
    Children and Family                8   5  
    Total                                 31
```

Answer (score 0):

//You Can Try like this..I am not Clear about your table
1.First

```
Create table #tblfinal(genre nvarchar(200),filmnum int,renttime int)

insert into #tblfinal(genre,filnum,renttime)
select genre, count(film_id),0
from film  group by genre union all
select genre,0, count(rented_item.rental_Num)
from  rented_item group by genre

select genre,filnum,renttime  from #tblfinal  union all
select 'Total',0,(select sum(renttime) from #tblfinal)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use union to add more results and you can avoid temporary tables with common table expressions

```
with
t1 as
(select genre
      , count(inventory.film_id) as film_num
 from      film 
      join inventory using (catalog_num) 
 group by genre
)
, t2 as
(select genre
      , count(rented_item.rental_Num) as rent_times
 from      film 
      join inventory using (catalog_num)
      join rented_item using(film_id)
 group by genre
)
, t3 as
(select t1.genre
      , t1.film_num
      , t2.rent_times 
 from           t1
      left join t2 on t1.genre=t2.genre
)

select * from t3
union all
select 'Total' as genre
     , 0 as film_num
     , sum(rent_times) as rent_times
from t3
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to remove the double quotes.  Escaping identifiers just makes things more complicated.

You can simplify the query using window functions.  I would suggest:

```
select f.genre, i.num_films, count(*) as rent_times
from film join
     (select i.catalog_num,
             count(*) over (partition by catalog_num) as num_films
      from inventory
     ) i
     using (catalog_num) join
     rented_item
     using (film_id)
group by genre, i.num_films;
```